# animation jumps from one to another

Tags: javascript, css

i am trying to add an animation where a logo will slide to the middle then another animation will kick in after that using a delay, but after the first animation it snaps on to the net one after having is as position relative

here is my code:

```
        <h1 class="intro-title">
            Hello world
        </h1>

    <h4 class="scroll-down">Scroll Down</h4>

    <div class="arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>



    <div id="color1"></div>
    <div id="color2"></div>
    </div>

     <img class="logo" src="logo/logo.png">


    <div id="scroll">
        <button class="intro-button">Check it out!</button>   
    </div>

function logoShift() {
    $('.logo').css({ 
        transform: 'translateY(-95%)',
        right: '90px',
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        position: 'relative'
    });



}
```

Comment: You could actually use a library for this like WOW.js https://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/ or if you are wanting to write this custom let me know.

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work how i wanted it too, i am looking to build it custom i have it all working as i wanted apart from the snapping part if that makes sense